condition number of 8e11 on a double type 3000 by 3000 matrix
I am working with a matrix on a language who follows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754  I guess that means my double is 64 bit.
In my case I have to keep doing something like solving $A X = B$, where $B$ has a condition number of 8e11 and $A$ has a condition number of about 1e7. Matrix sizes are about 3000 by 3000
Is 8e11 bad or not? Reading here: https://www.alglib.net/matrixops/rcond.php

Let's consider an example. Let the condition number of matrix A be
equal to $10^4$. This means that if the machine precision is $10^{-15}$, the
system of linear equations will be solved with precision $10^{-11}$.
Suppose that our estimate can vary by 90% and equals $10^3$. This means
that we can expect a higher precision: $10^{-12}$. The difference is not
very big because it is not the value of error that's important but its
order. On average, 10% of the difference could be ignored since it is
less than one decimal digit.

but what's the "precision" of my 64-bit double?

Where are you getting your A and B matrices from? If they are a result of other operations, you may be able to design a better algorithm.

64 bit floats (doubles) have 53 bits of precision (approximately 16 digits). One piece of good news for you is that the condition number of B doesn't matter since each column of X determines a unique column of B so the norm on B that matters is the maximum ratio of biggest element to smallest element for each column in B.

Would you add a few words about the importance of the ratio of the biggest to the smallest element of each column of $B$?

While, strictly speaking, @oscarsmith's answer is correct, in practice a condition number of $8\cdot 10^{11}$ in double precision means that it is infinite -- that is, that your matrix has an eigenvalue (or multiple eigenvalues) that for all practical purposes is zero. Whether that's "bad" or not of course depends on what it is you are trying to do with the matrix -- but it should prompt you to investigate whether you expect a zero eigenvalue and if you don't then how it happened that your matrix has a zero eigenvalue.
